Convolution inequality $\big{\|}\|f(x,\cdot)*g(y)\|_{L^\infty_x}\big{\|}_{L^2_y}\leq C\big{\|}\|f(x,y)\|_{L^1_y}\big{\|}_{L^\infty_x}\|g\|_{L^2}.$
I am trying to prove that for sufficiently nice and non-negative $f\colon\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g\colon\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ we have the convolution inequality $$\big{\|}\|f(x,\cdot)*g(y)\|_{L^\infty_x}\big{\|}_{L^2_y}\leq C\big{\|}\|f(x,y)\|_{L^1_y}\big{\|}_{L^\infty_x}\|g\|_{L^2}.$$
Attempt at proof: If we can exchange the norms $$\big{\|}\|f(x,\cdot)*g(y)\|_{L^\infty_x}\big{\|}_{L^2_y}\leq\big{\|}\|f(x,\cdot)*g(y)\|_{L^2_y}\big{\|}_{L^\infty_x}$$ on the left hand side then we can apply Young's convolution inequality: $$\|f(x,\cdot)*g(y)\|_{L^2_y}\leq C\|f(x,y)\|_{L^1_y}\|g\|_{L^2}.$$ But I can't justify the exchanging of the norms... it is obviously not true in general but is it true for convolutions of non-negative functions?

Your convolution inequality is not true in complete generality. Consider the function $f_R(x,y)= 1_{[-R,R]}(x) 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(x-y)$ and $g(y)=1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(y)$, then we have $\Vert f_R(x,\cdot)\Vert_{L^1}=1_{[-R,R]}(x)$ and $\Vert g \Vert_2=1$. On the other hand, we have
$$ [f_R(x,\cdot) * g](y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_R(x,z) g(y-z)dz = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{[-R,R]}(x)1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(x-z) 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(y-z) dz. $$
Now use the change of variables $s=z-y$ and we get
$$ [f_R(x,\cdot)*g](y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{[-R,R]}(x)1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(x-y-s) 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(-s) ds. $$
In particular, we have
$$ [f_R(y,\cdot)* g](y) = 1_{[-R,R]}(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(0-s) 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(-s) ds = 1_{[-R,R]}(y). $$
Thus,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\sup_x [f_R(x,\cdot)*g](y)\right)^2 dy =2R.$$
Your inequality for this case reads
$$ \sqrt{2R} \leq C. $$
No constant is going to make this work as we can let $R$ go to infinity. In fact we could have picked $R=\infty$, but I wanted to show that we can choose $f$ in any $L^p$ and things still break down.
Note that we could replace the indicator functions by suitable nonnegative bump function. Hence, I can make all my functions smooth.
